# Power Automate connection to Dynamics 365/CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, power-automate

I use Power Automate based on a trigger to get data and access a contact list from CRM to send the information to.
The Power Automate no longer works as Microsoft has deprecated the connection between Power Automate and CRM.

Has anyone got an alternate solution to access CRM and send emails based upon a trigger?

Comment: You can still connect PowerAutomate to CRM, but the connector is called the `Common Data Service`

Comment: any followup questions?

Comment: Short Update: The Common Data Service is now deprecated too. The new connector ist called „Dataverse“

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Dynamics 365 Connector is deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/important-changes-coming#dynamics-365-connector-is-deprecated) but we have the replacement CDS connector like @jasonscript commented.

> Dynamics 365 apps such as Dynamics 365 Sales, Dynamics 365 Customer
> Service, Dynamics 365 Field Service, Dynamics 365 Marketing, and
> Dynamics 365 Project Service Automation, use Common Data Service as
> the data source.
>
> The Dynamics 365 connector is deprecated, but continues to work until
> removed. More information: Dynamics 365 Connector is deprecated.
>
> Do not use the Dynamics 365 connector for new flows. Use the Common
> Data Service (current environment) connector whenever you can. If the
> Common Data Service (current environment) connector does not fit your
> needs, use the Common Data Service connector.
>
> The Common Data Service (current environment) connector should be your
> first choice because it provides the most capability and best
> performance. However, it does not currently provide certain
> capabilities that the Dynamics 365 and Common Data Service connectors
> do, such as the ability to connect to multiple environments. The
> Common Data Service connector provides the same capabilities as the
> Dynamics 365 connector, but also provides substantially improved
> reliability.

[Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/connection-dynamics365)